# How to re validate controls on view?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation

I have a view file in c# MVC, and I have such a situation like once I click on submit button my page validates with model and if it is not complete the validation process my view means .cshtml file show validation message accordingly, but the thing is like if I pass valid input after that validation process the message not hide its still over there, is there any standard way to hide those error messages. once I pass valid input

validation like Required, Regex, length and all from model

Sample code is

View

```
<div class="col-md-12">
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.full_name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.full_name) } })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.full_name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

model

```
[Required(ErrorMessage ="Full name can't be blank!"),
RegularExpression("^[a-z,A-Z, ]*$", ErrorMessage = "Full name is not valid!"),Display(Name ="Full Name")]
public string full_name { get; set; }
```

Comment: Would you provide a sample of your code?

Comment: You can update your question with these samples. By the way, need a sample of your controller and view, too. Are you using jQuery Validation?

Comment: I have modified, now can you please review that if it is help at all @Babak

Comment: are you using client-side validation, or just server-side?

Comment: just server side validation @ADyson

Comment: in that case the validation controls will not change until you re-submit the form. Since MVC comes with the ability to do automatic client-side validation via jQuery Validate, you could use that. Then your validation will be much more responsive, including showing/hiding the messages as soon as the user finishes entering values into the field. It's quite easy to enable. Most MVC validation tutorials would show you how.

Comment: how do enable that feature or how can I achieve that @ADyson

Comment: As I just mentioned, it's explained in [lots of places](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=mvc+client-side+validation&oq=mvc+client-side+validation&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.3902j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) already

Comment: Ohh, Okay those validations are alternative, and I also go through that as well but I want to work with server validation without re-submit

Comment: " those validations are alternative"...no they're not, if you specified your validation rules via Data Annotations on your model properties, then MVC will automatically mirror those rules in the HTML and JavaScript. You can't "work with server validation without re-submit" - that's logically impossible. You can't run serve code without sending a request to the server.

Comment: Thank you @ADyson for this clarification.

Comment: No problem. Like I said if you find a tutorial on validation in MVC it will explain it all. I suggest taking the time to read about it so you fully understand how everything is supposed to work.

Comment: Thanks again @ADyson i'll sure to take tour of that document